# list btrfs subvolumes within a specific qgroup (quota0

Tags: ubuntu, backup, btrfs

I need to determine what data would be lost by deleting a specific `qgroup`. X-Y is that I have a `qgroup` taking up 50GB of exclusive/unique space that I am suspicious is stale/unreferenced, but don't know how to prove it before deleting.  I recently deleted a handful of older subvolume/snapshots to free nvme space.

This shows the qgroup at issue:

```
# btrfs qgroup show /home
...
0/259    75.03Gib    53.62GiB
```

But unique to this qgroup, I don't see any matching subvolumes that match (and I have not created any nested subvolumes or qgroups as best as I understand it).  `btrfs subvolume list` shows matching subvolumes for every other `qgroup` ID that I spot check (including `0/258`, `0/260`, and `0/261`).

How can I see what subvolumes would be deleted, if any, if this qgroup were to be deleted/destroyed?